# Объясните как работает создание двумерного динамического массива(int (*array)[7] = new int[15][7];)

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы

Есть такой тип объявление двумерного динамического массива:

```
    unsigned n{3};       // количество строк
 
    int (*a)[2] = new int[n][2];
 
    int k{};
    // устанавливаем значения
    for (unsigned i{}; i < n; i++)
    {
        // устанавливаем данные для столбцов i-й строки
        for (unsigned j{}; j < 2; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = ++k;
        }
    }
```

Можете подробно объяснить как работает конкретно этот пример, а именно часть с объявлением.

Как я понял, создается указатель на массив из двух элементов типа int, потом в new int[n] этот указатель на 2 элемента int множится до n(и соответственно также появляются массивы на которые указывают эти указатели) и потом их уже заполняют циклом.
Почему количество столбцов ограничено константой и правильно ли я понял механику работы данного объявления?

Answer (score 1):

Запись `int (*a)[2] = new int[n][2];` создаёт двумерный массив из n строк, в которых находится 2 int-а. Чтобы было более понятно можно сделать другой аналогичной записью :

```cpp
typedef int row [ 2 ] ;
row * a = new row [ n ] ;
```

И `a[1]` будет иметь тип `row == int[2]`, а `a[1][1]` тип `int`.
Массив `int[2]` будет содержать два int-а и выглядеть в памяти так :

```
[0][1]
```

А массив типа `row` аналогично :

```
[0][0] [0][1] [1][0] [1][1] .. [n-1][0] [n-1][1]
```

Чтобы вычислить место в памяти для доступа к таким массивам, нужно знать размерность строки и адрес будет вычислен компилятором так :

```
адрес[i][j] = начало + i * размер типа row + j * размер типа int
```

В языке C++ отказались от плавающего размера типа row, а в Си пока можно использовать так :

```c
int n=fun();
int m=fum();
int ar[n][m];
```

Причин отказа много, не я решал этот вопрос, а создатели языка.